# Implement AEM SPA in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, create-react-app, aem

I am working on a POC to migrate our AEM SPA application from create-react-app to Next to take advantage of the feature rich platform including SSR and SSG capabilities. I have my index and catch-all page routes written and have ported over the existing AEM App component and component library. The app loads when hitting all of the URLs properly, and
I am able to see the network calls to the AEM server return the models successfully. However, I run into with rendering components the recommended AEM way ( App extends the AEM Page class and returns child pages and components which are generated under the hood by the AEM library based on the model). I am able to force components to render when I import them directly and render with the props found in the JSON, but this is not practical as that should be handled by the library).

One thing that I think may be the issue is the import-components which is dynamically imported on the Page index seems not work as intended.

```
const importComponents = dynamic(() => import('../src/components/import-components.js'))
```

This imports a script that imports other components.

Again, using the work around I mention above, I am able to import and render components but I shouldn't have to write my own framework for that, the AEM library should handle it. Has anyone else attempted to bring an AEM SPA into Next? If so, what did you do that worked? Any code samples would be appreciated as it doesn't seem that a lot of people are using AEM in this way.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is a link to a bare-bones repo [aem-next-example](https://github.com/loganmurphy/next-aem). I tried getting this up and running in codesandbox but there were some issues with the AEM libraries. There is no readme in the repo but steps are simple:

1. clone the repo and cd into the root dir
2. run npm install
3. run npm run dev
4. open the browser to http://localhost:300 (any path works, I have implemented a dynamic Page since AEM pages are dynamic, however we are hard-coding the server-side route/model for the purposes of this example so it'll work regardless of the URL path)

Caveats: There are a lot of workarounds here, I feel like AEM wasn't intended to be used with Next, which is why there is a tutorial for around 20 other CMSs on nextjs.org, but NOT AEM. I am also intermittently getting an error loading the page due to "self not defined" (somehow related to module imports, not sure how to resolve this other than reload the page when I see it, at least it isn't happening with a production build)

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @juliomalves it's difficult due to our private code base, I'll try pulling something together field-stripped and making it available, will be a few days but I'll get that ASAP.

Comment: @juliomalves I updated the post to include a link to a bare-bones example repo. I added comments in the AEM App component detailed expected behavior and my workaround (the Image component will render if you leave the code as is, comment my hack and it won't render, the AEM library will handle this)

Comment: Are you trying to use Next components within AEM page (as known as SPA editor) or Next js app is running outside of AEM?

Comment: Trying to use aem components within a next application as deployed with npm run dev. Not worried about the authoring instance currently, for now maintaining a separate code base for that